# c# - IEnumerator get type

Tags: c#, types, ienumerator

I'm working with IEnumerator in C#. I don't know how can I get the current item's type. In the enumerator are not just int, string, etc. If You can, please give me an example too. Thanks!

Comment: `enumerator.Current.GetType()`?

Comment: It would *really* help if you'd give an example of what you're trying to achieve. Your question is very unclear at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

If your intention is to obtain the `Type` of each element in the sequence, call `GetType` on each element like this:

```
var enumerator = sequence.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    Type currentType = enumerator.Current.GetType();
}
```

However, if your intention is to branch according to the type of the element, I suggest that you use the [`is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/scekt9xw.aspx) operator instead:

```
var enumerator = sequence.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    if (enumerator.Current is string) {     
    }
    else if (enumerator.Current is int) {
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call `GetType` method on `Current` item. That will give you the underlying type.